# Using ArcPy and PyGRASS tools in same Python script?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, grass-gis, python-2.6, typeerror

I´m trying to write a Python script, that includes different ArcPy / ArcGIS commands and want to combine it with GRASS geoprocessing tools.

Unfortunately importing the GRASS libraries doesn´t work.

```
import grass.script as grass
```

ends in an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named script
```

I know that GRASS GIS installs it's own Python version. Isn´t there a way to combine the ArcGIS and the GRASS GIS installation of Python? I tried copying the pygrass module (or what I thought it might be it) to the C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\Lib\site-packages\ folder. I´m getting a different error message, but it´s still not working.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\site-packages\grass\script\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from core   import *
  File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\site-packages\grass\script\core.py", line 38, in <module>
    gettext.install('grasslibs', os.path.join(os.getenv("GISBASE"), 'locale'))
  File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\ntpath.py", line 96, in join
    assert len(path) > 0
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

I´m using ArcGIS 10 and GRASS 6.4.2 on a Windows 7 64 Bit machine.

Answer (score 6):

Most likely the grass version of Python has installed its own Python bindings into a grass specific site-packages.  One non-ideal option would be to add the following prior to importing `grass.script`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('\path\to\grass\bindings.py')
```

What this is doing is temporarily adding grass to your `$PYTHONPATH` so that your ArcGIS10.0 Python installation finds it when searching for imports.

Comment: Hey Jay, thanks for your tip. I think the respective folder is .../etc/python/grass/script/. Do I have to reference a specific .py file or all of them?

Comment: Yes, for example, if I wanted to add the gdal bindings from another folder I would need to use `python_install/site-packages/osgeo/gdal.py`.  Does a `grass.py` script exist in the `grass` directory?

Comment: There are several .py files, unfortunately none with a clear name like grass.py . I have tried to reference all of them. Unfortunately it still doesn´t work. :-(

Comment: Do you get a meaningful stack trace or is it just an import error?

Comment: It´s a similar error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\Lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 312, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "D:\Martin ZEPP\Import-GRASS.py", line 7, in <module>
    import grass.script as grass
ImportError: No module named grass.script

Comment: Hmmm....one more idea for you to try: It looks like you can install GRASS without using the bundled python, as per the linked post.  Perhaps try a reinstall and force GRASS to use the Arc python install? http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2012-June/065178.html

Comment: I you asked about pygrass but maybe this post is on interest anyway. It talks about arcpy bindings for gdal. http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1eec30bf5fa042a5a2227b094db89441